# Trying to add a new row based on a check in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
s <- c(1,1,1)
r <- c("2017-01-01 12:34:17", "2017-01-01 12:52:18", "2017-01-01 13:17:18")
t <- c(1,1,1)
g <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(s, as.POSIXct(r), t), nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
names(g) <- c("DeviceId", "Time", "Success/Fail")
g$Time <- as.POSIXct(g$Time, origin = '1970-01-01')
```

I am trying to write a function that loops through the data set and checks to see if the row and its successor's Time are more than 15 minutes apart.  Then, the loop would add a row to the data set with the same DeviceId, the row's time plus 15 minutes, and 0 in the Success/Fail column.  Here's what I've come up with:

```
f <- function(g) {
  for(i in 2:nrow(g)) {
    if(g$Time[i] - g$Time[i-1] >= 15) {
      q <- list(g$DeviceId[i-1], g$Time[i-1] + minutes(15), 0)
      y <- data.frame()
      y <- rbind(g, q)
      arrange(y, Time)
    } else NULL
  }
}  


f(g)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you are after.  I am sort of unclear about the success/fail indicator (-1 assigned to cases where the times are less than 15 minutes apart).  It avoids the loop by using the `lag()` function in `dplyr`.  Presumably, your data has more than one device so I added `group_by(DeviceId)`

```
x <- g %>%
  group_by(DeviceId) %>%
  mutate(
    lTime = lag(Time, order_by = Time),
    dTime = Time - lTime,
    `Success/Fail` = if_else(dTime >= 15, 0, -1),
    newTime = Time + minutes(15)
    )

y <- x %>%
  select(DeviceId, newTime, `Success/Fail`) %>%
  rename(Time = newTime) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rbind(g, .)
```

Comment: Quicker way to get there: `dTime = c(0, diff(Time))`, no intermediate lagging necessary. (It does assume the data is correctly sorted.)

Comment: It's definitely miles ahead of what I was looking to do.  I'll look into using a more dplyr based answer than a for loop.  Any idea why it inputs NA into the Success/Failure column between the first and second row of the data set?

Comment: @KyleLigon there is an NA because the first entry in the data does not have a lag.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably occurred.  I'm not familiar with the lag function.  Thanks for showing it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. I think the previous example is removing the first row? when the last row should be dropped (no time period after it).

```
g <- data.frame(DeviceId = rep(1,3), 
            Time = ymd_hms(c("2017-01-01 12:34:17", "2017-01-01 12:52:18", "2017-01-01 13:17:18")), 
            Success_Fail = rep(1,3))

g %>% 
  transmute(DeviceId = DeviceId,
            Time = Time,
            t = lead(Time)) %>% 
  drop_na %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(t2 = if((t - Time) > 15) {Time + minutes(15)} else {NA},
         Success_Fail = 0) %>% 
  dplyr::select(DeviceId, Time = t2, Success_Fail) %>% 
  bind_rows(g) %>% 
  arrange(Time)
```